# Gentle introduction to non-autonomous dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, book-recommendation

I've been spoiled by Strogatz' *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* book. It's really pleasant to read, intuitive, light on the formalism, with a friendly, personable tone that focuses on intuition and concepts over rigor.

However it only covers autonomous systems; the course I'm taking has moved to non-autonomous systems, and all the resources I find are extremely heavy on the formalism and much more difficult to extract intuition from.

Does anyone have a beginner-friendly resource similar to Strogatz that covers non-autonomous dynamical systems?

Comment: Strogatz is very bad, you should try to avoid embarking on the same mistake.

Comment: @JohnB There's no place here for your arbitrary value judgements.

Comment: That's your opinion. Yes, quite good to study it "from the viewpoint of robotics". That was extremely funny! :) Try not to be so rude.

Answer (score 0):

I found my favorite so far. The conversational tone is from the viewpoint of robotics, and it has a fairly understandable, logical build up that keeps formalism minimal and practical. As nonautonomous is a smaller niche than autonomous, I think this is probably as good as it gets: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa02/caltech/mls93-lyap.pdf

However some of the definitions on "local" vs "global" are missing details that should be supplemented with https://engineering.purdue.edu/~byao/Research/Supplements/Lyapunov.pdf